# Vimeo API - Paused video cannot play again

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, embed, vimeo

I am working on a site that has two embedded Vimeo videos. When you play the second video, if the first is playing, the first will be paused. This works beautifully. However, once the first video is paused, it will not play again. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

```
var vimeo = {
    videos: [],
    currentVideo: null,
    init: function (element, i) {
        var videoData = {
            'title': $(element).html(),
            'id': 'video-' + i,
            'url': $(element).attr('href'),
            'width': $(element).data('width'),
            'height': $(element).data('height') 
        };
        $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoData.url) + '&api=1&player_id='+ videoData.id +'&width='+ videoData.width +'&height='+ videoData.height +'&callback=?', function(data){
        $(element).html(data.html);
        $(element).find('iframe').load(function(){
                player = this;
                $(player).attr('id', videoData.id);
                $f(player)
                .addEvent('ready', function(player_id){
                    vimeo.videos.push($f(player_id));
                })
                .addEvent('play', function(player_id){
                    if (vimeo.currentVideo != null) vimeo.currentVideo.api('pause');
                    vimeo.currentVideo = $f(player_id);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.vimeo').each(function(i) {
        vimeo.init(this, i);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the "play" event instead:

```
.addEvent('play', function(player_id){

                        for (var i = 0; i < vimeo.videos.length; i++) {
                            // console.log(vimeo.videos[i].element.id + '=' + $f(player_id) + '?');
                            if (vimeo.videos[i].element.id != $f(player_id).element.id) {
                                vimeo.videos[i].api('pause');
                                // console.log('paused ' + vimeo.videos[i].element.id);
                            }

                        }

                    });
```

Your initial script actually worked just fine for me, as long as you alternate between the two videos- but the problem was, as soon as you try to pause and play the same video, it would be stuck, because your variable "currentVideo" held the previously played video, even if it was the first video you were looking at and paused, and would then immediately pause it again.

My method may be a bit "brute force", pausing all other instances, but it seems to work OK for me, and shouldn't cause noticeable overhead if you don't display more than a handful of videos at a time. Instead though, you might perhaps experiment with a "currentVideo" variable that doesn't only change when not NULL, but also not equal to the video player referenced by player_id.

Also, it may have been helpful for you to have mentioned that you were using the Froogaloop API, had to do a bit of sleuthing there!

Here's the complete page that worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vimeo = {
        videos: [],
        currentVideo: null,
        init: function (element, i) {
            var videoData = {
                'title': $(element).html(),
                'id': 'video-' + i,
                'url': $(element).attr('href'),
                'width': $(element).data('width'),
                'height': $(element).data('height')
            };
            $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoData.url) + '&api=1&player_id='+ videoData.id +'&width='+ videoData.width +'&height='+ videoData.height +'&callback=?', function(data){
            $(element).html(data.html);
            $(element).find('iframe').load(function(){
                    player = this;
                    $(player).attr('id', videoData.id);
                    $f(player)
                    .addEvent('ready', function(player_id){
                        vimeo.videos.push($f(player_id));
                    })
                    .addEvent('play', function(player_id){

                        for (var i = 0; i < vimeo.videos.length; i++) {
                            // console.log(vimeo.videos[i].element.id + '=' + $f(player_id) + '?');
                            if (vimeo.videos[i].element.id != $f(player_id).element.id) {
                                vimeo.videos[i].api('pause');
                                // console.log('paused ' + vimeo.videos[i].element.id);
                            }

                        }

                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.vimeo').each(function(i) {
            vimeo.init(this, i);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="vimeo" href="http://vimeo.com/48312847">A video</a>
<a class="vimeo" href="http://vimeo.com/41219986">Another video</a>
</body>
</html>
```